# Format a C# date time to dd/MM/yyyy using momentjs

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm trying to format a c# DateTime object which I receive from a web API call in this format:

**2017-01-28T00:00:00+11:00**

How could I format this datetime to `dd/MM/yyyy` basically 28/01/2017?

`moment("2017-01-28T00:00:00+11:00").format('dd/MM/yyyy')`

Any idea why this yields "Sa/01/yyyy"? I'd like to solve this without manually splitting date parts as the target format is dynamic, ie: dd/MM/yyyy may as well be MM/dd/yyyy.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try DD instead - been a while since I used momentjs, but I just looked up the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to see that `d` refers to day of week and `D` to date of month - while there's no mention of `dd`, it does mention `ddd` (3 letter abbreviation) and `dddd` (full day of week) ... perhaps `dd` is acceptable as a two letter abbreviation but is undocumented ... either way, you want to use `D`

Comment: If you want the format to across *different cultures*, then you can use *'L'*. Refer @ http://momentjs.com/docs/#localized-formats

Answer (score 1):

Yess, try DD

For more references, look at this documentation :

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 0):

Moment has quite a few formats which you can use to manipulate your date object.

Most of them are following, with reference date: *31st December, 2016*:

- **YYYY**    -   2016
- **YY**      -   16
- **Q**       -   4 (quarter)
- **MM**      -   12
- **MMM**     -   Dec
- **MMMM**    -   December
- **D/DD**    -   31
- **Do**      -   31st
- **DDDD**    -   366 (day of year)
- **X**       -   1483142400 (Unix timestamp)
- **x**       -   1483142400000 (Unix timestamp in ms)

So, in your case, you can use `format('DD/MM/YYYY')`